# Can first N eigenvalues have the same real value?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Essentially the subject line: Suppose there is a matrix of shape $[M,M]$ where $M \ge N$. We perform eigen decomposition and observe that the leading $N$ eigenvalues have the same, real value. Is this hypothetical scenario possible?

In my anecdotal experience, the leading eigenvector (largest eigenvalue) dominates and the effect of trailing eigenvectors (lesser eigenvalues) vanishes. And this seems sensible; if you performed some transformation on an arbitrary vector with some matrix once or twice, you'd probably observe the effects of all eigenvectors to some degree. But if this transformation was recursively applied an infinite number of times, the leading eigenvector would dominate the others in the long run. (Which is why the possibility of equal & maximum eigenvalues is so interesting to me.) I suspect the answer is "no" (perhaps equal if imaginary.)

Comment: What if $M$ is the identity matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Take $I$ to be the identity matrix; then all eigenvalues of $I$ are equal to 1. You can also force the bound $N$ to be tight: Simply take the the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1, \ldots, 1, 1/2, \ldots, 1/2)$ where there are $N$ entries of value 1 and $M - N$ entries of value $1 / 2$.